# how can i destructure massives in massive? can i use recoursion or should i use forEach here?

Tags: javascript

The Western Suburbs Croquet Club has two categories of membership, Senior and Open. They would like your help with an application form that will tell prospective members which category they will be placed.

To be a senior, a member must be at least 55 years old and have a handicap greater than 7. In this croquet club, handicaps range from -2 to +26; the better the player the lower the handicap.

My code looks like this, and it returns only one value. How i should destructure it to make all values appear in result str?

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
  let str = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data == '') {
      return 'error!';
    } else if (data[0] >= 55 && data[1] > 7) {
      str.push('Senior');
    } else {
      str.push('Open');
    }
    return str;
  }
}

console.log(openOrSenior([
  [18, 20],
  [45, 2],
  [61, 12],
  [37, 6],
  [21, 21],
  [78, 9]
]));
```

Comment: You should read values like this `data[i][0]` and `data[i][1]` since your data is 2d array

Comment: Second thing you're returning after first iteration itself, whereas your return statement should be out of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're returning from the function at the end of the first loop iteration which is why you're only getting one result.
2. Your arrays are nested so you either need to identify the age and handicap by their index (0 and 1 respectively), or use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)  to give the elements at those indexes more meaningful labels.

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {

  const arr = [];

  // Destructure the age and handicap from 
  // the nested array of the current iteration
  // of `data`
  for (const [ age, handicap ] of data) {

   // If age is less than 55 we can
   // immediately add "Open" to the array
   // and then continue with the next iteration
   if (age < 55) {
     arr.push('Open');
     continue;
   }

   // We now know that the age qualifies it
   // for "Senior", but does the handicap measure up?
   // If not push "Open"
   if (handicap >= -2 && handicap <= 7) {
     arr.push('Open');
     continue;
   }

   // If the age qualifies and the handicap is
   // within the "Senior" range push "Senior"
   if (handicap > 7 && handicap <= 26) {
     arr.push('Senior');
     continue;
   }

   // If none of the conditions are met add
   // an message instead
   arr.push('Not qualified for either position');

  }

  return arr;

}

console.log(openOrSenior([
  [18, 20],
  [45, 2],
  [61, 12],
  [37, 6],
  [99, -3],
  [21, 21],
  [78, 9]
]));
```

Comment: thank you for detailed responce, now it makes more scense for me